# Determine the number of ways $12$ identical action figures can be given to $5$ children so that each child receives at most $3$ action figures

Tags: discrete-mathematics, generating-functions

Use generating functions to determine the number of different ways $12$ identical action figures can be given to $5$ children so that each child receives at most $3$ action figures

So far I have come up with the generating function of: $$(1 + x + x^2 + x^3)^5$$
To correspond to each child having either $0, 1, 2, $ or $3$ action figures with each child representing a factor. But, I am confused as to how to expand this. Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Multiply it out like any polynomial, and then you are interested in the coefficient of $x^{12}$, because this corresponds to giving out $12$ of the figures.

Comment: No, @Token, don't multiply it out, you lose the whole advantage of generating functions that way. Get an expression for $1+x+x^2+x^3$ (it the sum of a geometric progression, after all), and make use of the Binomial Theorem to expand the $(1-x)^{-5}$ that you will get. Or look at any of the 100 previous times questions like this have been asked, and answered, here.

Answer (score 2):

Enough has been said about the generating function approach in other comments and answers. Perhaps it's also worth mentioning that generating functions can easily be expanded using [Wolfram|Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/).

But in the present case generating functions are overkill. The most efficient solution to the problem is to note that you're looking for the number of ways of distributing $5\cdot3-12=3$ gaps among $5$ children without restrictions. This is $\binom{3+5-1}{5-1}=35$.

Comment: Is the reasoning behind your answer that if we gave each child three action figures, we would have distributed three too many, so we must select three action figures to not distribute to the five children?

Comment: @N.F.Taussig: Exactly.

Comment: That's an elegant approach.

Answer (score 2):

It is convenient to use the *coefficient of* operator $[x^n]$ to denote the coefficient of $x^n$ of a series.

> We obtain
>   \begin{align*}
> [x^{12}]&(1+x+x^2+x^3)^5\\
> &=[x^{12}]\left(\frac{1-x^4}{1-x}\right)^5\tag{1}\\
> &=[x^{12}]\left(\sum_{k=0}^{5}\binom{5}{k}(-1)^kx^{4k}\right)\left(\sum_{n=0}^\infty\binom{-5}{n}(-x)^n\right)\tag{2}\\
> &=\left(\binom{5}{0}[x^{12}]-\binom{5}{1}[x^8]+\binom{5}{2}[x^4]-\binom{5}{3}[x^0]\right)
> \sum_{n=0}^\infty\binom{n+4}{4}x^n\tag{3}\\
> &=\binom{5}{0}\binom{16}{4}-\binom{5}{1}\binom{12}{4}+\binom{5}{2}\binom{8}{4}-\binom{5}{3}\binom{4}{4}\tag{4}\\
> &=1\cdot 1820-5\cdot 495+10\cdot 70-10\cdot 1\\
> &=35
> \end{align*}

*Comment:*

- In (1) we use the formula for the *[finite geometric series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series#Formula)*
- In (2) we use the *[binomial series expansion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_series)* for the denominator
- In (3) we use the linearity of the *coefficient of* operator and the rule $[x^{p-q}]A(x)=[x^{p}]x^{q}A(x)$. Note that we only need to respect $4$ of the $6$ summands of the series, since terms with exponents greater than $12$ do not contribute. We also use in the right series the binomial identity
  \begin{align*}
  \binom{-p}{q}=\binom{p+q-1}{p-1}(-1)^q
  \end{align*}
- In (4) we select the coefficients from the right series accordingly to the *coefficient of* operator

Answer (score 0):

You're correct in forming the generating function

$$
F = (1 + x + x^2 + x^3)^5
$$

Now, you're looking for the coefficient of $x^{12}$ (Since each $x$ represents a figure, you want 12 of them. The coeffieint will tell you the number of ways $G$ produced the $12$ - which to us gives the number of ways to distribute $12$)

However, expanding it out makes us lose the advantage of using generating functions in the first place. Rather, we can notice that

$$ 1 + x + x^2 + x^3$$ is a geometric series starting from the term $1$, with common ratio $x$, and 4 total terms.

The formula for any geometric series with $n$ terms that has starting term $a$ and common difference $r$ is

$$
G = a + ar + ar^2 + \ldots + ar^n = a\times \frac{r^n - 1}{r - 1}
$$

Hence, for us,

$$
a  = 1 \\r = x \\ n = 3
$$

Hence,

$$F = \left (1 \times \frac{x^4 - 1}{x - 1}\right)^5 = \left (\frac{x^4 - 1}{x - 1}\right)^5
$$

Simplify $F$ using the binomal theorem and take the coefficient of $x^{12}$ to arrive at the answer